# Using FreeType extension in GWT?

Tags: gwt, libgdx, freetype

I'm trying to use the freetype extension in my project, and it works fine in Desktop and Android, but gives a ClassDefNotFoundException in HTML5. I know it's not imported/inherited right, but both freetype.jar and freetype-sources.jar are in its build path.

What needs to be done to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

It does not work with gwt and they are not going to fix it. Take a look at this issue: 
[issue](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1279)

> "Project Member #1 badlogicgames
>   Extensions relying on native code (gdx-audio, gdx-bullet, gdx-image, gdx-freetype) can not be ported to HTML5 i'm afraid."